# Trigger a group of requests in paw form e.g. jenkins/script

Tags: jenkins, paw-app

I am new to both jenkins an paw and was wondering if there is any posibility for jenkins/a script to trigger a group of requests in paw.

I could not find anything about this at the paw.cloud homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the Paw Support the other day. At the moment (29. Nov 2017) Paw cannot be triggered via a script from "outside". But they would like that feature but cannot ensure if or when this will be available.